# AJAX loading files that use global resources, causing GET errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My project uses MVC style coding, so I have a main controller (index.php) that loads in the modules that I need from subfolders, like support/support.php, profile/profile.php, etc.

[image: directory]

In each of the subfolder files (like profile/profile.php), I use resources from js/ and css/ in the main folder.

The problem is when I load these via JQuery.load(), and index.php grabs these requests like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/master.css' type="text/css"/>
```

Which causes errors like these:

[image: cry]

Any idea how to fix this? I could change the div I use for loading into an iFrame and fix it, but I'd rather not.

How do I stop index.php from reading href="../css/master.css" and other resources used by subfolder files?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your server configured to serve up static files from those urls?

Comment: has nothing to do with php , it's that paths are all relative to the page you are loading into. It is the browser that makes those requests . Try removing the `..` or make the url's absolute

Comment: In which file do you have this code ? `<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/master.css' type="text/css"/>` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen It's in the main folder css/master.css

Comment: Ok, in which file do you load the `css/master.css` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I load css/master.css for every file including index.php and all subfolder files like profile/profile.php, default/default.php, etc

Comment: The paths inside the `master.css` is which points to the css are not right i.e., If you see the image you posted `projects/Rebelsec/style.css` which expects `projects/cssRebelsec/style.css` but in the other case it can't able to find `projects/css/style.css` . So, i recommend you to check and follow uniform path inside the `master.css`

Comment: So, for blank debug case , you can try this `<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/master.css' type="text/css"/>` or `<link rel='stylesheet' href='../../css/master.css' type="text/css"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my question wasn't too clear since the method I'm using is overly complicated (I'm a noob at coding anyway);

Pretty much every subfolder file has it's own style.css which is then interpreted by index.php, causing the GET errors. There's no real way of fixing this unless I somehow figure out a way for javascript to ignore the subfolder .

I ended up using iFrames to avoid this error; it makes it easier on the controller but also increases the load time by a little bit. That's fine for now.. but in the words of Arnold Schwarzenegger, "I'LL BE BACK!"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../../css/master.css' type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: One sec, my question wasn't clear enough. I have individual style.css for each subfolder. So when index.php loads default/default.php, it also loads all the stylesheets for default/default.php. So index.php ends up reading `<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/master.css' type="text/css"/>` as well, which is what's causing that error

Answer (score 1):

create a global variable define('CSS_PATH','Absolute/Relative path');

also try to create Base_url